# How to fix these package errors?

Tags: android, package, jakarta-mail

I have done something similar to this post [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

But getting these errors [Error](http://gyazo.com/a2a9550a3d0a3bdbc3fb3c57cd8921de)

I have downloaded the Java Mail API but I don't know how to import it into the android studio IDE. PLease could someone help me

Comment: I don't know why people down voting the question, if you don't like to answer it why don't you just leave it or if you don't understand my question ask me to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You need to put the *.jar files in project_path/src/main/libs.
Right click *.jar file and add as library.

Comment: it comes in a zip file, so after extracting the file, am I just copying and pasting the jar files in to the directory you specified ?

Comment: Right click it and hit 'Add as library'

Comment: I am so sorry but where am I right clicking ?? so I have my project on android stuido and I have right clicked on my project but there's no option called add as library.

Comment: Note that the menu bar, select Project

Comment: If your JavaMail implementation comes in a zip file, you're using a very old version.  Get the latest version from the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate your libs by editing your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('<path to your jar>')
}
```

Source: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup